# (react)I get multiple arrays because of the .map() function, how can I set the state into one single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, frontend

Guys I'm a little confused here on how to get one single array on the state.

Right now this is how i'm setting the state

```
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get(`api/photo-data`).then(res => {                                      
            this.setState({photoData:[res.data]})               
            this.state.photoData.map((value, idx) => (
                value.map((val, idx) => (
                    this.setState({categories:[val.field_categories]})
                ))
            ))      
        })                              
    }
```

but this is the output I get,

```
{photoData: Array(1), categories: Array(1)}
```

or

```
categories: ["Portrait"]
photoData: [Array(23)]
```

So actually I have inside photoData the categories that I need but once i set them inside the state.categories they come on a separated array.

How can I have one object or array with the categories and remove the duplicate as well?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use componentWillMount [anymore](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Also setState is asynchronous so after you execute a setState and ask for `this.state` it will not be the state you just set, you have to use a [callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

However; in your code you can set the state for photoData and categories in one go:

```
componentWillMount() {
  axios.get(`api/photo-data`).then(res => {
    //do you want photoData to be an array containing
    //  an array of data? why not just set photoData to res.data?
    const photoData = [res.data];
    //use res.data to map
    const nonUniqueCategories = res.data
      .map(
        val =>
          //I am assuming field_categories is an array of primitive values
          val.field_categories
      )
      .flat(); //make [[cat1,cat2],[cat1,cat4]] into [cat1,cat2,cat1,cat4]
    //get unique categories
    const categories = [...new Set(nonUniqueCategories)];
    this.setState({ photoData, categories });
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you brother, understood and worked perfectly, using variables is easier to work with the data,

Answer (score 0):

This would be correct. And don't use `componentWillMount` for side-effects. Use `componentDidMount` and default state with empty array for example

```
componentWillMount() {
            axios.get(`api/photo-data`).then(res => {                                      
                this.setState({photoData:res.data})               
                this.state.photoData.map((value, idx) => (
                    value.map((val, idx) => (
                        this.setState({categories:[val.field_categories]})
                    ))
                ))      
            })                              
        }
```

Comment: You just badly copied componentWillMount for original quesion.

Answer (score 0):

To flatten the array, you can use the spread operator when updating the state. E.g.

```
const allCategories = [...firstCategories, ...secondCategories];
```

where firstCategories and secondCategories are arrays themselves. This will create a single flattened array.

To remove duplicates, you either need to iterate through each category as you're adding them and check if it is already in the array, or you can use a Set object.

```
const uniqueCategories = new Set(allCategories);
```

To turn this back into an array, simply use the spread operator again...

```
const uniqueCategoriesArray = [...uniqueCategories];
```

Comment: thanks, I'm trying to accomplish something similar, but I can't find the way to set the state properly, I think because I'm setting the state inside the map, that's why i'm getting several values instead of one array

Comment: Why don't you set variables to what you want first, then set the state afterwards? May make your code cleaner, and help you understand what's going on better

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, I worked more with variables and it worked great!

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://brittdepetter.com/api/photo-data`).then(res => {                                      
           const photoData = [res.data];   
           const categoryList = res.data.map(val => val.field_categories);
           const categories = [...new Set(categoryList)];
           this.setState({ photoData, categories});
        })                              
    }
```